# Change Name AVD in android studio

Tags: android

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NzC2z.png)

I want to change the AVD name on Android Studio, how do I change it ?, I ask for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pencil icon in actions. Then change AVD name from the dialogue that comes up.

Comment: but are they limited?

Comment: Limited in what context?